# Can't update table 'profiles' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am not sure here how i should write this trigger.

I want to remove profiles and images when a user record will be removed.

Whenever i tried to remove user this exception appeared

> Can't update table 'profiles' in stored function/trigger because it is
> already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

*Note: this is an example trigger script. in my actual situation i am not using foreign key constrains to cascade those records*

Here is my profiles table trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_remove_trigger
        BEFORE DELETE on users
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM profiles WHERE user_id = OLD.id;
        END
```

Here is my images table trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER profile_remove_trigger
            AFTER DELETE on profiles
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                DELETE FROM images WHERE profile_id = OLD.id;
            END
```

Comment: Neither of the published triggers would cause the error you are seeing when deleting users - do you have an after delete trigger on profiles?

Comment: *Note: this is an example trigger script.* They're correct. I think you have over-simplified the code losing the problematic point.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes , in my actual trigger it's AFTER DELETE in profile_remove_trigger.Question Updated. can it be causing problem ?

Comment: No - you must have a trigger on profiles which includes a statement which actions profiles to cause the error you are seeing. ALSO deleting from images and profiles should happen when you action users so should be in the users trigger (which BTW should be an AFTER trigger)